# Node enlisting fails when using ssl on MaaS

Tags: maas

Trying to get ssl working with MaaS (MAAS Version 2.1.5+bzr5596-0ubuntu1 (16.04.1)).
I'm working with a certificate I've signed by an internal CA.
I've enabled ssl in apache and the web ui is all set.
I've also changed the maas url to use https as per the documentation.
I've added the "ca-certs" module to the enlist preseed file with my internal ca certs.
Nodes fail to enlist.

Anyone run into this before with a similar setup?
Is there some additional documentation on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a process where I unsquashfs the daily "squashfs", chroot into the directory, add my CA certificate, jump out of the chroot, mksquashfs the newly edited directory, then finally copy the "updated" squashfs to the correct boot-resource location in MAAS.

Example:

- mkdir scratch
- cd scratch
- cp /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/current/ubuntu/amd64/generic/xenial/daily/squashfs ./
- unsquashfs squashfs
- chroot squashfs-root

  - add your certificate to the correct place for ubuntu
- update-ca-certificates
- exit
- mksquashfs squashfs-root/ squashfs
- cp squashfs /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/current/ubuntu/amd64/generic/xenial/daily/